# Flutter custom font weights not getting picked up

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

Using google fonts I have no issues with getting font weights to display correctly. But as soon as I use a custom font I have trouble. I'm using the `sofia pro` font and I've put the fonts into my assets folder and set up by `pubspc.yaml` as following:

```
  fonts:
    - family: SofiaPro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProUltraLight.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProLight.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProRegular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProMedium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProSemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProBold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProBlack.ttf
          weight: 900
    - family: SofiaProRegular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/SofiaProRegular.ttf
          weight: 400
```

I'm then referencing the font in two ways - once where it's in its own font family with no other weights and once where it's in with a list of other weights.

```
Container(
  height: height,
  child: Center(
  child: Text(
  "This text has weight w400",
  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SofiaPro', fontSize: size, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  )),
),
Container(
  height: height,
  child: Center(
  child: Text(
  "This text has weight w400",
  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SofiaProRegular', fontSize: size, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  )),
),
```

So, the only difference is the font family I'm referring to, but the text displayed is only shown correctly for the one where it's in a family by itself. For the other one I get the weight of the first font in the list. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's no font family *SofiaProRegular* at all in the fonts that you provide.

Please note that you're adding `assets/fonts/SofiaProRegular.ttf` twice both for *SofiaPro* and *SofiaProRegular* family.

If you want to use the same font in two font families try to copy the font file under a different name.

Comment: I only added SofiaProRegular to try and show that things work when there's only one font weight (ie, it'll display the correct weight). I initially started with just the SofiaPro theme where every font shows as ultra-lightweight (as it seems to use the first font in the list)